# 2 log files using one log4j2.properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a class and 2 logers as below. wanted to create main.log and recon.log files using log4j2.properties.

I am trying with the below its working for one logger only, how to add the second logger to the same log4j2.properties?

```
final static Logger mainlog = LogManager.getLogger("mainlogger");
final static Logger reconlog = LogManager.getLogger("reconlogger"); 

name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file
property.basePath = ./logs/
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${basePath}/recon.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern= %msg%n
loggers=file
logger.file.name=reconlogger
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```